# Отложить выполнение файлов php

Tags: php, include, sleep

**Задача**: запустить поочередно с определенной задержкой ряд php файлов.
Пытался следующим образом - в общий php файл, подключил нужные, и поставил между ними sleep. Однако, подключенные файлы начинают выполняться одновременно:

```
<?php

include 'file_1.php';

sleep(70);

include 'file_2.php';
```

***Цель в общем***: одним нажатием (запуском одного файла) провести поочередный запуск множества файлов, выполняющих свой код, а не перебирать их все вручную.

**Как можно доработать данный способ, либо использовать иные варианты реализации данной задачи**? Буду благодарен за идеи

*(подключаемые файлы производят парсинг сайтов-доноров и загружают информацию на сайт)*

Comment: Подгружать данные можно через ajax с задержкой.. Тут всё зависит от того, что именно вам надо подгружать (т.е. что за действия должны производить подключаемые файлы)

Comment: Подключаемые файлы проводят парсинг сайтов-доноров, загружают информацию на сайт

Answer (score 0):

Открытие в новой вкладке и с задержкой(не очень хороший вариант, но на скорую руку)

```
<?php
    $file....=данныеилитаймвсек
    $suite="laravel.php?blog2=".$file07."&blog3=$time.....     ";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.open("'.$suite.'");</script>';
    ?>

    <?php laravel
$time=$_GET('blog3');
    set_time_limit($time+10);
    sleep($time)

    $file ='people.txt';

    $current = file_get_contents($file);

    $current .= date("H:i:s");
    // Пишем содержимое обратно в файл
    file_put_contents($file, $current);

    ?>
```